# I want a class template to have a sort method only if the type passed to the template is an int

Tags: c++

First of all, I know this question has been answered, but I don't really understand how to do it

I'm creating my own vector class (for learning purposes), and I want it to have a sort method that I've alreay coded only if the type passed to the template is int.

```
template<typename T>
class vector
{
    T* _arr = new T[5]{ 0 };
    size_t _size = 0;
    
public:
    template<>
    void sort<int>()
    {
        // whatever
    }
};
```

Would It look something like that? BTW, I want that method to be defined inside the class.
How would you do it?

Comment: No, that is not correct.  You need to declare `sort()` in such a way that it utilizes [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) in its declaration, such as via [`std:::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). Sorry, my SFINAE kung-fu is not very good, so I can't make you an example, but there are plenty of them floating around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++20 has nice `requires` for that:

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
    T* _arr = new T[5]{ 0 };
    size_t _size = 0;
    
public:
    void sort() requires(std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    {
        // whatever
    }
};
```

For previous version, you have to use SFINAE

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
    T* _arr = new T[5]{ 0 };
    size_t _size = 0;
    
public:
    template <typename Dep = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Dep, int>, int> = 0>
    void sort()
    {
        // whatever
    }
};
```

or specialization (you probably have to create extra CRTP classes to limit specialization to extra method):

```
template <typename T> class vector;

template <typename T> struct vector_sorter {};

template <typename T>
struct vector_sorter<int>
{
private:
    vector<int>& self() { return static_cast<vector<int>&>(*this); }
public:
    void sort()
    {
        // whatever
        // use `self()` instead of `this` to access `vector<int>` members
        // such as `self()._arr`, `self()._size`
    }
};

template <typename T>
class vector : vector_sorter<T>
{
    friend vector_sorter<T>;

    T* _arr = new T[5]{ 0 };
    size_t _size = 0;
    
public:
// ...
};

#if 0 // Or specialize the full class
template <>
class vector<int>
{
    int* _arr = new int[5]{ 0 };
    size_t _size = 0;
    
public:
    void sort()
    {
        // whatever
    }
};
#endif
```

Comment: wait, im i lil bit lost here... is c++ 20 alreay out??, oh and daaaaaaaamn your good

Comment: "*is c++ 20 alreay out??*" - yes, it was finalized early this year (hence the 20 in its name).  The number in the name is the year of its release - C++20 in 2020, C++17 in 2017, C++11 in 2011, C++03 in 2003, C++98 in 1998.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ye but i thought it was gon be released in at the end of this year

Comment: C++20 was technically finalized back in February, then the draft was sent out for ballot approval in September, and a final publication will be made near the end of the year.

Comment: It's less relevant to worry about the C++XY ISO standard final publication, but more relevant to worry about whether C++XY has been finalized _and_ whether the compilers you wish to support support the parts of C++XY you wish to use.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm sorry I don't understand this line `vector<int>& self() { return static_cast<vector<int>&>(*this); }`

Comment: To specialize only sub-part, using special class might help, but they don't have direct access to member of derived class. That `self` method allow to have access to member. You might look at [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for more details.

Comment: @Jarod42 and that way, a vector of strings doesn't have that sort method right?

Comment: Only specialization actually allows to not have the method, `requires` and SFINAE "discard" it at usage.

Comment: `vector_sorter<std::string>` uses primary template which is empty class. only specialization `vector_sorter<int>` has the `sort` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to disable the function if your vector type T is not an integral type (e.g. std::string or such...

```cpp
    // Make a template parameter Integer the same as type T
    // Then enable this function based on if Integer type is an integral type
    template<typename Integer = T,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, bool> = true>
    void sort()
    {
        std::cout << "sort" << std::endl;
    }
```

example here: https://godbolt.org/z/KzhYj7

This is quite easy to read - and if you have not yet moved on to c++20 this should work from c++14 onwards (IIRC)...

though I have to say the `requires` from c++20 looks pretty neat - more for my own amusement: https://godbolt.org/z/vaMc3o - also has **Jarod42**'s c++20 `requires` answer in it for comparison - that is sweet and so much more readable/easy :)

### edit

Couple of other methods if you don't have c++20

**constexpr**

Here you can have a compile time check for type correctness - but not necessarily fail to compile - maybe you just want nothing to happen, or print an error - or throw or whatever...

```cpp
    void sort()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value)
            std::cout << "sort" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Error: not an integral type\n"; // runtime error
    }
```

**static assert**

Quick, simple!

```cpp
    void sort()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Can only be integral type");
        std::cout << "sort" << std::endl;
    }
```